# Google Apps Script as callback URL from external site for oauth

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0

Sorry I don't have much knowledge in how this stuff works so...

I have a Bitrix24 site running and it has an API, it uses OAuth 2.0 protocol.

I want to create a Google Apps Script web apps (or API executable if it's more appropriate) that will interact with that external API.

From what I understand from the process, I call a page in the Bitrix24 site, which includes a callback URL, and the authentication info is sent to that callback page (https://training.bitrix24.com/rest_help/oauth/authentication.php).

I need to know if I can use Google Apps Script as this callback page. I have been searching but I don't think it's possible to use a web app's function, but maybe I'm looking at it from a wrong angle.

I hope someone can help in how this should be done, or say it's not possible at all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by `use Google Apps Script as this callback page`? You would like to call that API from Apps Script?

Comment: Probably doable. Looks like standard oauth. Use [this](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2)

Comment: @Kessy it's when you call an external API, and you supply a URL as a parameter that the API method calls when it's done, to send feedback or data to. I can call Apps Script functions from the same Apps Script project, but I don't know if an external site can do that. Thanks!

Comment: Based on the last comment, have you checked [Class google.script.run (Client-side API)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)? This allows you to run apps script functions from another client.

Answer (score 1):

If it can help, I think there are 2 options :

1 - you can deploy a Web App with a doPost() function that will receive the Callback from Bitrix24. Example :

`function doPost(e) { Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)); }`

Deploy your Web App to be accessible to anyone, and with "Execute the app as me" option. Then get this Web App's URL (something like https://script.google.com/..../exec) and pass it as your Callback URL parameter when calling Bitrix24

2 - you can also call Bitrix24 directly from you GAS Web App, using a state token to generate the CallBack URL. More information here :
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/state-token-builder

Comment: Hi @Ujuj. Thank you, sorry for the late reply. It's been some time since I looked into this, but I think that my conclusion (for my needs) was it was not possible (limitation on the Bitrix24 side). Sorry I cannot remember the exact reason. Thanks again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).